# Why does compiling a swig binary only produce a `pyd` file when using cmake when manual commands also produce a `py` file?

Tags: python, swig

Building a swig module (C++ to Python) manually using the procedure in the docs produces two files, one `pyd` and one `py`:

```
/* File: example.h */
int fact(int n);
```

```
// example.c
#include "example.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int fact(int n) {
  if (n < 0) { /* This should probably return an error, but this is simpler */
    return 0;
  }
  if (n == 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    /* testing for overflow would be a good idea here */
    return n * fact(n-1);
  }
}
```

```
// example.i
/* File: example.i */
%module example

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "example.h"
%}

/**
 * @brief compute n factorial
 * @param n number
 */
int fact(int n);
```

Then

```
D:\swigwin-4.0.2\swig.exe -python .\example.i
```

produces `example_wrap.c` and `example.py`. Users then use a setup.py for building the final binary, a `pyd` file.

However, I need to build my swig module using cmake within a larger project. Using the `UseSWIG` module:

```
set(Python_ROOT_DIR "C:/Miniconda3")
find_package(Python COMPONENTS Interpreter Development NumPy)
        message("Python_EXECUTABLE ${Python_EXECUTABLE}")

find_package(SWIG 4.0.0 REQUIRED
        COMPONENTS python
        )
include(UseSWIG)

swig_add_module(example python example.i example)

target_include_directories(example PUBLIC
        ${Python_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        )
target_link_libraries(example PUBLIC ${Python_LIBRARIES})
```

This procedure produces one single file called `_example.pyd`. So why does cmake only produce a `pyd` file while with manual commands you also get a `py` file?

Comment: The last argument to `swig_add_module` should be your sources or a header. I have used SWIG using CMake multiple times and it generates both a shared object and a library in the target language. Consider using the new syntax, `swig_add_library`, e.g. `swig_add_library(example LANGUAGE python SOURCES example.i)`. I also `include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})`

Comment: So `include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})` does the same thing as `include(UseSWIG)` but you're right about the `swig_add_module` being outdated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my problem had nothing to do with swig not generating the py file but with cmake not installing it.

A call like:

```
install(TARGETS Swiggity DESTINATION SwigOut)
```

Only installs the binary produced by swig, aka the `pyd` file. The `py` file is still burried somewhere in the binary tree.

Comment: Okay. For this purpose, I add a post build step and use `$<TARGET_FILE:someProject>` for copying, similarly for install targets

Comment: I did a subsequent call to `install(FILES ...)` which seemed to work okay. However, it'd be better if cmake just took care of this. I submitted an [issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21952) to kitware to see what cmake developers think.